# React Native Android GeoLocation

Tags: android, geolocation, react-native

I am trying to get the User's location in an Android React Native application. I've started by following the [React Native Geolocation Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) but am not having any luck.

I have added the appropriate permissions to the Android project and inserted this code in the react native app:

```
  componentDidMount() {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
        this.setState({initialPosition});
      },
      (error) => alert(error.message),
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );
    console.log("Initial position: " + this.state.initialPosition)

  }
```

I also have the `initialPosition` variable defined as 'unknown' just like in the tutorial. When the example runs, the `initialPosition` variable prints unknown. Then about 5 seconds later, the alert shows an 'undefined' error.

I am a bit confused as to what is going on because the error is null. Perhaps I am instantiating the "geolocation" incorrectly? Unfortunatly I am not able to find much information on this through searches so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this can help a bit:

1. You are logging the `initialPosition` outside the callback. This means that `initialPosition` will be unknown because the callback has not been run yet and thus the `initialPosition` variable has not been updated yet.
2. Try logging the `error` variable not just make an alert of `error.message`. It is possible that there is an `error`, but not an `error.message`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Printing the error returned "No available location provider" so at least now I have a direction to go in. Not sure why this wasn't stored in the message..

Comment: Have you tried, without enableHighAccuracy: true. I.E: enableHighAccuracy: false?

Comment: Turns out I did not have locations enabled on the device. Defiantly not one of my finer hours... Defiantly will need to catch that case in the future!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. try this code it may be helps you and define latitude and longitude variable in constructor inside this.state as null .
> 2. if you want to print json string then define a array in state then use by setting this.setState the array

```
 - Don't forget to give location permission in manifest file
```

- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

```
componentDidMount(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position)=>{
        //const ipos = JSON.stringify(Position);
        this.setState({
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          });
    },
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
  );
}
```